# Oracle count with group by returning empty rows

Tags: oracle

I am trying to build a query where it returns the count for each month (passing a start and an end date) of a certain value, the output should be like this

```
 Month Qtn
 ---------
 |July|0|
 |Augu|0|
 |Sept|0|
```

but I get no rows, the query is the following:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMM') AS XMONTH, COUNT(TT_CUSTOMERS.NAMES) AS QTY FROM TT_CUSTOMERS
WHERE COMPANY = 700
AND TT_CUSTOMERS.C1_LOOKUP_ID = 100
AND TT_CUSTOMERS.C2_LOOKUP_ID = 1
AND TT_CUSTOMERS.C3_LOOKUP_ID IN (70, 80)
AND TT_CUSTOMERS.ST_LOOKUP_ID = 90
AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) >= TO_NUMBER('20170701')
AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) <= TO_NUMBER('20170930')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMM') ASC;
```

I know it's because the query is returning no rows, so the XMONTH is emtpy and so also the qty is empty, but I can't figure out a way to get the output that I've shown.

Comment: I think the problem lies with `AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) >= TO_NUMBER('20170701')
AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) <= TO_NUMBER('20170930')`  dates should be compared as dates, not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming closed_date is of a date datatype...
and assuming all your other fields values are int and matches exist in the database...

I'd assume it's the numeric comparison of date values.  Compare a date as a date not as numbers.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMM') AS XMONTH
     , COUNT(TT_CUSTOMERS.NAMES) AS QTY 
FROM TT_CUSTOMERS
WHERE COMPANY = 700
  AND TT_CUSTOMERS.C1_LOOKUP_ID = 100
  AND TT_CUSTOMERS.C2_LOOKUP_ID = 1
  AND TT_CUSTOMERS.C3_LOOKUP_ID IN (70, 80)
  AND TT_CUSTOMERS.ST_LOOKUP_ID = 90
  AND TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE >= TO_DATE('20170701','YYYYMMDD')
  AND TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE <= TO_DATE('20170930','YYYYMMDD')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TT_CUSTOMERS.CLOSED_DATE, 'YYYYMM') ASC;
```